# How to restrict a multibranch pipeline job not to trigger builds when multibranch pipeline is created

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins.groovy file which i use as a seed job for my multibranch pipeline creation.

I don't want the multibranch pipeline job to trigger build when the pipeline is created as we have 10 or 20 branches in a repository which all gets triggered when a multibranch pipeline is created.

So i need the builds to be triggered only when the commit is done in any branches or when a new branch is created.

Please provide me a way to achieve this in groovy or through configurations in Jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Branch API plugin and Basic Branch Build Strategies Plugin.

Add skipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing() in your jobdsl.